# JPA: Query an embeddable List inside an entity

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, criteria-api, embeddable

I am trying to "extract" Embeddable classes based on some criterias from a list in an Entity. Either with the help of JPQL or Criteria API. I am not a pro at this, so please help me out. Been googling for 4 hours solid for an answer without any results.

These are the classes:

```
@Entity
public class PostOffice {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "CARRIERID"))
    private List<PostalCarrier> carriers;

}


@Embeddable
public class PostalCarrier {

    @JoinColumn(name = "area")
    private Area area;

} 


@Entity
public class Area {

    @Id
    private int code;
}
```

So, basically what I'm trying to achieve is something like this.

```
TypedQuery<PostalCarrier> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p.carriers FROM PostOffice p 
WHERE p.id = ?1 AND p.carriers.area.code = ?2", PostalCarrier.class);

    query.setParameter(1, postOfficeId);
    query.setParameter(2, areaCode);
```

I only want to get a list of the PostalCarriers at specific area code from a specific PostOffice.
Any help is much appreciated! :)

---

I think I'm almost there, but keep getting the following error:

```
 Error compiling the query [SELECT h FROM PostOffice p INNER JOIN p.carriers h 
 WHERE p.id = ?1 AND h.area.code = ?2], line 1, column 71: unknown state or 
 association field [area] of class [com.test.PostalCarrier].
```

Answer (score 2):

You must make a join to the PostalCarrier. You can't access a property from a collection. Thus, `postalcarrier.area` isn't correct.

```
select postalcarrier from PostOffice p
inner join p.carriers postalcarrier
where p.id = :postOfficeId
and postalcarrier.area.code = :areaCode
```