# JPQL Query a list of Strings inside an Entity

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpql, entities

I'm using Java EE7 with a GlassFish 4.1 Server to build a system where basically you can post Ideas, and each Idea may have tags.
I've declared the entity Idea as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "IDEAS")
public class Idea implements Serializable {

// Id, description, etc.

@ElementCollection
private List<String> tags;

// Getters, Setter, etc.
}
```

After reading [JPA: Query an embeddable List inside an entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137610/jpa-query-an-embeddable-list-inside-an-entity) I tried to find by Tag the following way:

```
public List<Idea> getIdeasWithTag(String tag) {
    String queryStr = "select ideatags from Idea i "
            + "inner join i.tags ideatags "
            + "where ideatags.tags = :pTag";
    Object res = em.createQuery(queryStr)
            .setParameter("pTag", tag)
            .getResultList();
    return (List<Idea>) res;
}
```

But I'm getting a TransactionRolledbackLocalException caused by:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager:
>   Exception Description: Problem compiling [select ideatags from Idea i inner join i.tags ideatags where ideatags.tags = :pTag]. 
>   [61, 74] The state field path 'ideatags.tags' cannot be resolved to a valid type.

I appreciate any help, thanks in advance!!

Comment: you don't have the same situation as that linked post ... your List is of a String, not an Embeddable. Consequently your JPQL "ideatags.tags" makes no sense at all. So are you trying to find all Idea objects that have a specific "tag" contained?

Comment: Oh thanks (i'm new to JEE and JPQL). Exactly, I want to get all the Idea objects that contain that "tag"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some problems with your query:

```
select ideatags 
from Idea i inner join i.tags ideatags
where ideatags.tags = :pTag
```

You want the result as Idea but you select a List.

You get your List tags in ideatags, therefore you cant get the attribute tag of ideatags.

if you want to search in the list you have to use IN.

You can try this:

```
select i
from Idea i
where :pTag IN (i.tags)
```

Comment: Ok gracias, makes sense. But I'm getting "Syntax error parsing [select i from Idea i where :pTag IN i.tags]. 
[35, 35] The left parenthesis is missing from the IN expression.
[42, 42] The right parenthesis is missing from the IN expression." when I try this. Do you know what it can be??

Comment: I tried adding parenthesis like this (:pTag IN i.tags) but didn't work either

Comment: Put the parentheses around the "i.tags" (since that being a List was only introduced in JPA 2.1 IIRC). Some JPA implementations are weak on that

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select e from entity e WHERE :element in elements(e.listOfStrings)
```

Answer (score 0):

elements() - this work!

where :pTag IN (i.tags) is not work (

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).